# Get static reference to Errai RequestDispatcher in service

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I'm trying to upgrade the Errai version in an GWT project. We only use the errai bus, and previously we got the ErraiService from the ServletContext to get the `RequestDispatcher` and send messages. Upgrading from errai 2.0.Beta2 to 3.0.3, though, that no longer works.

I know that in the client you can get the RequestDispatcher through `ErraiBus.getDispatcher();` but that doesn't seem to work on the server code.

How can I statically access the `RequestDispatcher` from the server without using CDI in order to send a message?

I can see in their source code that:

```
@Singleton
public class ErraiServiceImpl<S> implements ErraiService<S> {
```

has a reference to the request dispatcher I need. Is there some wa I can get a reference to a singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ErraiService service = ErraiServiceSingleton.getService();
```

I had to look in their source code to find this little gem. Not sure why it isn't mentioned anywhere, but it's a great way to use the Errai Bus without their CDI.